Calculate the error distribution of fractional abundance values ​between classes (a spectral mixture analysis issue)
I am trying to estimate the distribution of the under- and overestimation errors that I found in the outputs of a spectral mixture analysis (SMA), i.e. abundance fractional maps (AFM).
Specifically, AFMs are images composed of 10 bands (10 land use classes) whose pixels for each band show the fractional value [0,1] representing the abundance of that specific class in the specific pixel.
To estimate the error I have a "ground truth" that has identical dimensions to the AFM but that contains the real values ​​of abundance on the ground.
The first step was to calculate the Bias Error, subtracting the AFM from the ground truth, with resulting values ​​ranging from -1 (max underestimation) to 1 (max overestimation) for each pixel and class.
I would now like to calculate the overall distribution of these errors, for example: when a class is unerstimated by -0.2, to which other class/classes were assigned those 0.2 missing points? And so for all the under-overestimation errors of all the classes.
What is the most appropriate method to use in these cases?
P.S.: I work in Python
